# Как найти неизвестную в формуле с интегрированием?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

```
    fl1 = lambda p: ((gamma*self.lamb*(p-f)/(1+f*p))*self.const.eta1(self.k,self.f, p)-C).subs('f', self.f).subs('k', self.k)
    f1 = integrate.quad(fl1, self.f, math.tan(math.radians(alpha+phi)/2-(math.pi)/4))
    fl2 = lambda p:(((self.lamb*gamma*(p-f)/(1+p**2))*(self.const.eta2(self.k,self.f,p))-C)).subs('f', self.f).subs('k', self.k)
    f2=integrate.quad(fl2, self.s, self.f)
```

Пытаюсь найти неизвестную C из уравнений выше, но на данном этапе из за того что C=symbol('C') пишет ошибку: `TypeError: can't convert expression to float` Как это исправить??

Comment: Указывайте в вопросе и в тегах, какие библиотеки вы используете. В вашем случае SymPy,я так понимаю?

Comment: @MrMorgan, ДА и scipy